# Row timestamps in Bigtable - when are they updated?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

The definition of `TimestampRangeFilter` from [Bigtable's Go API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/46a19d54380f7a69bc14cfc011b6e7e03e6de86e/bigtable/filter.go) is:

> TimestampRangeFilter returns a filter that matches any rows whose timestamp is within the given time bounds.

Is the row timestamp updated when:

- Any column value is written/changed within that row?
- The row key is updated?
- The row is created?
- Any other circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a documentation bug. It should read something like:

> TimestampRangeFilter returns a filter that matches any cells whose
>   timestamp is within the given time bounds.

Rows themselves don't have timestamps.

Comment: Docs fixed here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/commit/dd88571a2747f25e093c425b9a598db5bec04e57