# Google Bigtable: Timestamp scan

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I see that Bigtable is designed to only have 1 primary index, the row key.
However I now realize I want to scan Bigtable by a time range in which a row is added. How should I implement this? Is it possible or should I consider something else like Cloud Datastore?

Currently my row key is just a hash, like this: **ABC1234567**. Can I add a timestamp to it (e.g. **ABC1234567#20180524)** then use regex filter on row key to scan by time range? This scan doesn't have to be very fast. 
But then when I look for a hash (which needs to be fast), I need to use prefix scan instead of exact match. I'm not sure of the impact to performance this may incur.

Another solution is maybe to add another table to store timestamp info.

One more thing to consider is that I'm using the [Node.js client](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigtable/0.13.x) which is in alpha right now, so it may not have all the tools necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a lot of documentation here regarding correct time series schema design: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series.

In your specific case, appending the timestamp to the end of the hash would work. If you want to search for rows in March 2018 across all hashes, then you would need to do a full scan of the entire table every time you use a regex filter.

When you need to look up by hash, that will still be fast, as you would search by prefix and bigtable will be able to find it efficiently since it relies on lexicographical sorting.

The last option you alluded to, having a separate table, is known as denormalization, and is an option if you need both types of queries to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this question could be flagged as duplicated but I think this other question-answer might answer yours:

[Row timestamps in Bigtable - when are they updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287838/row-timestamps-in-bigtable-when-are-they-updated)

Also, you can check about the [TimestampRange here.](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.bigtable.v2#google.bigtable.v2.TimestampRange) and about the [composition of the key here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#empty-cells):

> Each row is essentially a collection of key/value entries, where the
>   **key is a combination of** the ***column family***, ***column qualifier*** and
>   **timestamp**. If a row does not include a value for a specific key, the
>   key/value entry is simply not present.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However as answered in that thread you provided, **TimestampRangeFilter** is used to filter cells, not rows, so it doesn't apply here. I suppose **TimestampRange** is used similarly.


About the composition of the key, that would also only apply when your data is of type time-series which mine isn't (my keys are just a collection of hashes). Though I did went with adding a timestamp to my key and it's working fine thus far.

Comment: Sorry Pepperoni, I might be wrong but, doesn't any cell have [timestamp, value and labels](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/reference/data/rpc/google.bigtable.v2#cell) ? And once you can filter a key cell because of it's timestamp, you can get the row related to that key, can't you?

I thought that since it says _**timestamp_micros**_

_The cell's stored timestamp, which also uniquely identifies it within its column. Values are always expressed in microseconds, but individual tables may set a coarser granularity to further restrict the allowed values._ Thanks a lot for your feedback!

Comment: I think the way it works is that you apply a filter for rows first then for each row a cell filter is applied. So if I want to filter row by cell timestamps, I would have to do a full table scan for the rows first, which is not ideal. I think it's obvious cause data in bigtable are "sorted" by row key and so row key is the only way to filter data without a full table scan.

Comment: Did you manage to achieve what you wanted after @Temu 's help? As you said I think you have to read the full table or, for the future, add the timestamp once you create the row.

Comment: @Iñigo yeah, I ended up adding a reverse timestamp to the end of my hash.